# SQL Join Two tables and create two fields, most likely needs a nested sql function

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi I believe I need to do some sort of complicated join

df1

```
   Date          creditcard_number    transaction_number   store
   2017-11-01    1234567891234567     1                    1
   2017-01-01    1234567891234568     00                   1
```

df2

```
   Date          transaction_number   store    orig_trans_number orig_date 
   2017-11-01    1                    1        00                2017-01-01
```

How can I do a join that creates two new fields (creditcard and orig_creditcard)?  This is where I am right now and I am stuck.

```
 Select df2.date , df2.transaction_number, 
 df2.store df2.orig_trans_number, df1.creditcard_number as  ?
 From df1 , df2, 
 Where
```

Df - Goal

```
   Date          transaction_number   store    orig_trans_number orig_date     creditcard_number     orig_creditcard
   2017-11-01    1                    1        00                2017-01-01     1234567891234567      1234567891234568
```

Comment: what columns in df1 and df2 have to match ?

Comment: i was thinking the join to be done on (trans number or orig_transnumber).   it would be great if I could also add in date and store to make the join stronger but I can't think of how to do this.

Comment: @guigoz i think this has to be a nested sql query.  first join on the orig_trans then on the trans_number.  Can you help?

Comment: really no need of nested query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a couple of joins to achieve this. This SQL query should work:

```
SELECT 
    df1.*, 
    df3.transaction_number as orig_trans_number, 
    df3.Date as orig_date, 
    df3.creditcard_number as orig_creditcard
FROM df1
JOIN df2 ON df1.transaction_number = df2.transaction_number AND df1.store = df2.store
JOIN df1 AS df3 ON df3.transaction_number = df2.orig_trans_number AND df3.store = df2.store
WHERE df1.creditcard_number = ?
```

example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/603c4/1

Comment: is there a reason why you add the tables to df1 vs df2

Comment: Im not too sure what you are asking. Are you referring to the fields in the SELECT or somewhere in the JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a join on Date, transaction_number, store

```
select  df1.Date, df1.transaction_number, df1.store, df2.orig_trans_number, df2.orig_date, df1.creditcard_number, df3.creditcard_number as orig_creditcard
from
  df1
  join df2 using (Date, transaction_number, store)
  join df1 df3 on df3.transaction_number = df2.orig_trans_number and df3.Date = df2.Date and df3.store = df2.store
```

df1 has to reappear aliased